# Run multiple Synergy servers

Tags: linux, bash, synergy

Currently I have a Windows PC & Linux workstation running Synergy. One is the client and the other is the server with the physical keyboard and mouse. I was wondering if it is possible to add another server that if available will be the main server. So for example, sometimes I want to use my Macbook Air keyboard and trackpad to control the Windows PC and the Linux workstation. Is this possible? I think to make this work Synergy would have to be able to run two servers at once or be able prioritize which server to use. I didnt see this option in the configuration setup but I thought I'd ask since I'm new to using Synergy. I think I have seen some people make it work using Bash scripts but I'd prefer not to have to run a script every time I do this. 
Thanks!